# set the alignment of title of navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to align the title of the navigation bar to the center in my app but it seems the title is staying on the right side (please find the screen shot). I'm using the code below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goToHomePage:)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];
}
```

in `viewWillAppear()` as below

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:offertitle];
```

and tried this too

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 120, 40)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
label.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
label.text=offertit;
self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

the title displays center aligned title when I hide the back button. Is there any method to set the appearance attributes of back button?

[image link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhjMi.jpg)

Can anyone guide me where i may have gone wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to use UILabel. You can directly use this code:

```
[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Your Title"];
```

and you're good to go! This code will automatically lay its self to the center of the navigation bar.

Or if you actually have an instance of UINavigationController, use:

```
[self setTitle:@"Your Title"];
```

Comment: I have same problem, but it did not work for me, I have got same results, as displayed in image in question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set self.title = "" in the viewWillDisappear method in the previous viewcontroller.

Eg. ViewControllerB is opening from ViewControllerA then set self.title = "" in ViewControllerA's "viewWillDisappear" method

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // this will appear as the title in the navigation bar
        UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
        label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // change this color
        self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
        label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"PageThreeTitle", @"");
        [label sizeToFit];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call this in ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)prepareNavigationTitle
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-50, 0.0, 240.0, 40.0)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text=offertit;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a navigation controller then just add: self.title=@"Your Title";

Answer (score 0):

Try using self.navigationItem.title = @"YourTitle"; this code will place the title in the center of the navigation bar .