# navigationbar, title, center alignment through code

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a number of of xibs where I manipulate the title of the navigation bar through code:

```
titleLabel.text = @"custom Title";
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

The problem I have is that in some cases I add to that bar a right or left button, or both, and whenever I do that the text alignment ends up being a little bit off and not centered proerly. How can I fix that?

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33365965/4768700

Answer (score 1):

Get the width of the barButton and subtract it from the label's width.

You can determine your bar button's frame through this method:

[Get the width of a UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066847/get-the-width-of-a-uibarbuttonitem?lq=1)

i.e.

```
NSInteger barButtonWidth = //determined through method above ^^^^^

titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(titleLabel.frame.origin.x, titleLabel.frame.origin.y, titleLabel.size.width-barButtonWidth, titleLabel.size.height);
```

Comment: this is not doing it, the label is still coming off center.

Comment: I didn't look into it any further, care to share any findings you've had?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found out a workaround it.

By adding the the buttons before setting the title view, xcode automatically sets the alignment properly. the order is important.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
UILabel *labelNav;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    labelNav=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 20)];
    labelNav.font=[UIFont fontWithName:boldFont size:15];
    labelNav.textColor=barTintColor;
    labelNav.text=kBoostBusinessHoursScreenTitle;
    labelNav.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    labelNav.center=self.navigationController.navigationBar.center;
    CGRect framelabel=labelNav.frame;
    framelabel.origin.y=12;
    labelNav.frame=framelabel;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:labelNav];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [labelNav removeFromSuperview];
}
```