# Navigationbar title alignment issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have set custom view as navigation bar titleView, when page is first view controller title is shown correctly in center

[image: Correct Image]

but when view controller is pushed from another view controller title is shifted to right

[image: Incorrect Image]

Code :

```
-(void)setUpTwoLineNavigationTitle {
    CGFloat width = 0.95 * self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44)];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    CGRect titleRect = contentView.frame;
    titleRect.origin.y = 4;
    titleRect.size.height = 20;

    UILabel *titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:titleRect];
    titleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    titleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    titleView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    titleView.text = @"";
    [contentView addSubview:titleView];

    CGRect subTitleRect = contentView.frame;
    subTitleRect.origin.y = 24;
    subTitleRect.size.height = subTitleRect.size.height - 24;
    //CGRect subtitleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 24, 220, 44-24);
    UILabel *subtitleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:subTitleRect];
    subtitleView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    subtitleView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0];
    subtitleView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    subtitleView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    subtitleView.text = @"";
    [contentView addSubview:subtitleView];

    contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = contentView;
}
```

Can anyone help me in correcting this ?

Github link : https://github.com/iamabhiee/NavigationTitleDemo

Comment: Your contentView is too wide, so its pushed to the right by the back button. Do you need it to be 0.95 times the view's width? At 0.6 times the width, it looks like it would be centered.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks but If I do that then initially it looks like left aligned when child view is loading and then shifted to center

Comment: I don't see that happening in your test app. In any case, you need to make the view narrower to get it centered. You may have to do other things as well to get rid of the problem you mentioned.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33365965/4768700

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a workaround, it may be useful, the idea is to use a UILabel as the `titleView` of the `navigationItem`. This way you don't have to manually calculate and adjust its frame, it will automatically centered by the system. The range in the code is hardcoded though.

```
// here to create a UILabel
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.numberOfLines = 0;

// set different font for title and subtitle
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Title\nSubTitle"];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.0] range:NSMakeRange(6,8)];

// set line spacing
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragrahStyle setLineSpacing:6];
[paragrahStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

label.attributedText = string;
[label sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```