# Navigation bar title alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] 

    setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
         @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:RED_COLOR ,NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:16]}];
        self.navigationItem.title=@"ORDER DETAILS";
```

I am using the above code to set title for view controller, but the title is not coming properly. In some view controller it is coming as expected

Comment: ,refer this link,It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903013/navigationbar-title-alignment-issue

Comment: You can create your custom label and add to navigation bar title view, set the alignment you want.

Comment: @Elangovan I need without custom label

Comment: @vijeesh try giving background color for your title may be the tittle label content is too big to afford the navigation bar area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // here to create a UILabel

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.numberOfLines = 1;
// set your custom font for title

    NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"ORDER DETAILS"];
    [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];

// set line spacing
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragrahStyle setLineSpacing:6];
    [paragrahStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragrahStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    label.attributedText = string;
    [label sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

copied from :[Navigationbar title alignment issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903013/navigationbar-title-alignment-issue)

or else the better idea is made the title as an UiImage and u can use that image as Navigation bar title. Use a properly sized 44x44 pt image with 2x and 3x versions.

```
UIImageView* titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orderpng.png"]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

UIView* titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)];
imageView.frame = titleView.bounds;
[titleView addSubview:imageView];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
```

enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a Xamarin Solution:

```
var label = new UILabel();
            label.Text = title;
            label.Font = UIFont.FromName(Strings.OpenSans_Bold, 30f);//This is a custom font. You will have to add it to your project first.
            label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Left;
            label.SizeToFit();
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(label);
```